# YouTube Video Player Rendering Problems In 2011 Samsung SmartTV Devices

Tags: actionscript, youtube-api

My team and I are designing a video-based app for Samsung connected-TVs and Blu-Ray players, and we were wondering if anyone has run into similar graphic rendering issues we've been having with the YouTube player. Namely, if we try to make an instructional help popup panel appear over the player window while a video plays, the popup will disintegrate as the video renders beneath, creating an ugly user experience. Likewise, occasionally the YouTube video player progress bar does not render in its entirely, but rather appears as a splotchy portion to the left, then renders in partially as the video plays and the marker advances along the progress bar to the right. [Please note: these issues do NOT happen in the Samsung emulators, NOR in any 2012 Samsung devices. They ONLY happen in 2011/2010 TVs and Blu-Ray players.]

In terms of the devices themselves and their runtime support, etc., here's what we are testing:

Samsung SmartTVs and BluRays (2010 and 2011): Flash8.0/ FlashLite3.1/ ActionScript2.0

Samsung SmartTVs and BluRays (2012 and 2013): Flash 10.1 / ActionScript 3.0

Thanks very much for any insights or suggestions for how to attack these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue too. It's just another bug and Samsung probably will never fix it as AFAIK they only provide this kind of support for current (2013) and previous (2012) year devices.

The last hope may be a workaround. Try creating a `MovieClip` filled with transparent rectangle over the affected area and move it around to force redrawing. Other hacks like that may also help.

**P.S.:** The fact that Flash doesn't seem to be the most popular way of building their apps makes the chance for future firmware update even closer to 0.